# How to authenticate Expo with workflow federation for autosubmission?

Tags: react-native, expo, github-actions, cicd, eas

I am trying to build a pipeline to deploy my app using Expo's eas build `--auto-submit` command. However, I am unable to generate a service account key for my organization. As an alternative, I am using workflow federation to authenticate my app. The authentication process works fine, but Expo still asks for the service account key during the build process.

How can I properly authenticate Expo with workflow federation so that Expo understands I am authenticated and does not ask for the service account key during the build process?

I have tried using the credentials key and writing the access_token to the google-services.json file, but neither of these methods has resolved the issue.

Here is my current code structure:

```
  - id: "auth"
    name: "Authenticate to Google Cloud"
    uses: "google-github-actions/auth@v0.4.0"
    with:
      create_credentials_file: 'true'
      token_format: "access_token"
      workload_identity_provider: "***"
      service_account: "***"
     
  - name: Set Google Credentials
    run: |
      echo "GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS=${{ steps.auth.outputs.access_token  }}" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      cp ${{ steps.auth.outputs.credentials_file_path }} google-services.json
  - name: ️ Submit to Playstore 
     run: cd apps/mobile && pnpm install && eas build --platform android --profile preview --no-wait --auto-submit-with-profile=development
```